# Trying to run a daemon with crontab

Tags: server, cron

Im very new to linux/ubuntu, and I learned a few stuff by setting up few nodes for cryptocurrencies like Zcoin. I keep bumping into one issue though!

In nodes, if your server is disconnected/offline/ doesn't run for whatever reason for more than 3h, they you are penalized and you are ending up in the end of the queue. Im hosting with Vultr at the moment(running ubuntu 16.04), and occasionally, they will put some servers into maintenance/reboot for hardware failure/some repairs.
 So, ideally , i would love a way to have a cronjob that could bring the daemon(the zcoin daemon in my case) back to life on every reboot !

At the moment, after i login to the server, i type those 2 commands:

1. `cd ~/zcoin-0.13.7/bin` and then
2. `./zcoind -daemon`

And that's it!
Can someone please tell me how on earth I need to put the syntax on the `crontab -e` ?!?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the [official supported method](https://github.com/zcoinofficial/zcoin/blob/master/doc/init.md) (I copied only the relevant parts regarding Linux and systemd):

> **Sample init scripts and service configuration for bitcoind**
>
> Sample scripts and configuration files for systemd, Upstart and OpenRC can be found in the contrib/init folder.

```
contrib/init/bitcoind.service:    systemd service unit configuration
```

> **4a) systemd**
>
> Installing this .service file consists of just copying it to `/usr/lib/systemd/system` directory, followed by the command `systemctl daemon-reload` in order to update running systemd configuration.
>
> To test, run `systemctl start zcoind` and to enable for system startup run `systemctl enable zcoind`

The [service itself](https://github.com/zcoinofficial/zcoin/blob/master/contrib/init/bitcoind.service) has a `Restart=always`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it. after **crontab -e**   i put on the last line :

```
@reboot ~/zcoin-0.13.7/bin/zcoind -daemon
```

I'll leave it here in case someone else finds it useful!